# Move entire Notes.app database from iPhone to Windows PC?

Tags: iphone, windows, data-synchronization, data-transfer, notes.app

I'd like to move the entire Notes.app database (all the notes, all the folders, all the file attachments inside the notes) from iPhone to Windows PC?

I've scanned a lot of documents with my iPhone's Notes.app, and I want to back them up (and view them on my PC should the need arise).

Comment: What have you tried so far, including looking at https://support.apple.com/ for the related support documents?

Comment: yeah, I did look there: there are no articles on Notes' db migration/transfer to Windows. I do not want to export it as PDF note by note. I do not want to view it online on iCloud. I want it to stay local. I want the actual db. Are you the one who closed my question?

Comment: I put in hold because it could be about not having access to the relevant support documents, about not beeing able to transfer Notes to a PC, about the availability of a Windows application able to *edit* iOS Notes.

Comment: "back them up (and view them" is fulfilled by a PDF export actually. Also, https://www.howtogeek.com/715949/how-to-view-and-edit-apple-notes-on-windows-10/ has some ideas about this, would they work?

Comment: I think my question is clear: "Move entire Notes.app database (all the notes, all the folders, all the file attachments inside the notes) from iPhone to Windows PC?" Exporting PDFs will not work in my case: I have 1000s of notes neatly sorted in nested folders according to the topic. I am not going to spend days exporting them one by one and re-sorting them again. And that is why I did not ask how to export them as PDF. I specifically asked to "Move *entire* Notes.app *database*". My question could not be clearer. Your false assumptions are on you.

Comment: And yes, I did the legwork: I checked Apple, Google, ChatGPT, and here. The question is _not_ trivial. I know myself that I could sync the iPhone to iCloud, then sync a Mac to the same iCloud, and then extract the SQLite DB from said Mac, I have done it before, *but*: 1. my notes are above the free tier amount (5GB), and I don't feel like paying to Apple just to move stuff to my other device that I own 2. I don't want my notes to be in the cloud 3. I don't have an access to a Mac at the moment.

Comment: No, https://www.howtogeek.com/715949/how-to-view-and-edit-apple-notes-on-windows-10/ absolutely has nothing to do with my question. It says how to access the iCloud.com - either directly, or via electron-like wrapper, or use Google. It doesn't explain how to transfer the data base files locally. The last thing I want is for Google (of all companies) to have access to ALL my private documents: health, financial, tax, etc.  That is why my question CLEARLY asked: "Move entire Notes.app database (all the notes, all the folders, all the file attachments inside the notes) from iPhone to Windows PC?"

Comment: I‘ve reopened the question, the details you added in the comments make it much more easy to understand the constraints you are facing.

Comment: @InfiniteLoop I doubt you can do it from your iPhone. Apple Notes is not even properly scriptable with Apple own tools. If you have the competency to extract the  `~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/NoteStore.sqlite `, it's better to pay for one month of 50GB iCloud (1€) sync, then close the account and do it on your Mac

Comment: @InfiniteLoop If you don't have access to a Mac, you might try to access them directly from iCloud.com where there is now an access, though I imagine it will be complex to automate it for 1000s of Notes.

Comment: Alternatively, you could buy a soft to explore the inside of your USB-connected iPhone from your PC and start from there. (it will likely mirror the structure on a Mac). I know there are some on the Mac, but don't know on PC.